# pointer has life of its own (MacBook Pro)

Tags: macos, itunes, macbook, touchpad

I have a MacBook Pro, and the mouse is randomly moving around, but it seems to be happening at only one place.  At my local Starbucks.

My Bluetooth is disabled, I have not installed any software that has ever been known to cause this issue.

I make sure that it isn't my trackpad, so when it starts happening I take my hands away from the computer itself, and it seems to go wherever it wants, mainly it seems to activate my itunes and when I try to take control, the pointer seems to fight me.

This although can be humorous, it can be annoying. It is almost like someone is using the wireless access point at the local Starbucks to attempt to remote access computers.

Am I being paranoid, or is this really a problem? I have looked online and noticed that this was with the older OS's but I am using the latest and greatest, so I can't imagine that the same issue is still a problem, or is it?

Comment: If you disable wifi, does the problem immediately stop?

Comment: Not always, it seems to be random. The last time I was able to stop it, I had to literally power off the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the plist files for mouse / trackpad?

bring up “Go To Folder”
~/Library/Preferences/ and choose Go
remove the ones that are relevant to your issue:
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist - Magic Trackpad
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist - Magic Mouse
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse.plist - wired USB mouse

Leave the user Preferences folder and reboot

Comment: I've done it, but I won't be able to know if it works till it either happens or not... on a side note, I don't use a Magic Mouse, or Magic Trackpad. The only thing I can think of it the wired USB mouse, but I normally don't use one on this laptop.